# What does `-B` linker switch do?

Tags: c, makefile, linker

I see a few [in this makefile](https://github.com/libhugetlbfs/libhugetlbfs/blob/6b126a4d7da9490fa40fe7e1b962edcb939feddc/tests/Makefile#L202). eg:

```
$(CC32) -B./obj32 $(LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS32) -o $@ $(LDLIBS) -Wl,--hugetlbfs-align $(filter %.o,$^)
```

What does this `-B` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a linker switch.  If it were a linker switch specifically it would be prefixed with `-Wl,` telling the GCC front-end to pass that option through to the linker.

The `-B` option is for the GCC front-end, and you can learn about its options here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html

Index of options here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Index.html

The `-B` option here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#index-B